# What does it mean for a distribution to fail to be a smooth function?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I am trying to understand what is meant by a singular support of a distribution:

[image]

So singular support is defined as the complement of the largest open set on which T (the distribution) fails to be a smooth function. My question is how can a distribution not be $C^\infty$ in the first place? By definition of the distributional derivative, we apply the derivative to the test functions which are all $C^\infty$ so it is impossible for a distribution not to be infinitely differentiable.

Comment: What about $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}$ in $\Bbb R^2$? Is it everywhere $C^\infty$?

Comment: @Bill, well, yes, there's some potential ambiguity about whether "smooth" means "differentiable" and whether that means "distributionally differentiable"... But I think you see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

A distribution $\phi$ is said to be a smooth function if there exists an actual smooth function $f$ satisfying $\phi(g)=\int f g dx$ for all test functions $g$. This is said to hold on an open set $U$ if the equality holds for all test functions with compact support in $U$.

Comment: Is your definition equivalent to the one I stated and to the common ones given in textbooks? In the textbook by Duistermaat, he states :The singular support of u, denoted by sing supp u,
is the set of all x in X that do not possess any open neighborhood U in X such that the restriction of the distribution from X to U is C infinity. This is from chapter 7 of the textbook. I am still not sure if he means if the  restriction map itself is C infinity, or if it is the restrcted distribution is C infinity.